# Zapier Storage & Conditionally Run

Tags: zapier

I am trying to use Zapier Storage in conjunction with Conditionally Run. The task I am trying to achieve is as follows:

If **value/child** exists **->** Complete Action A.

Else **->** Complete Action B.

The issue I am running into is the Storage App Returns no value if none is found. Meaning, there is no data for the 'Conditionally Run' app to go off which stops it running.

Is there a build in work around for when Zapier Storage finds no matching value?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: are you talking about using `Filter by Zapier`?

Comment: I was actually referring to Zapier Paths. I did find a solution built right in just today. There is an option to select value "does not exist". This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The Zapier paths and Zapier Filter options includes a "Does not exist" option. Selecting this allows the app run conditionally based on no value being returned from the Zapier Storage function.